# Solr get array elements per line in .csv

Tags: csv, solr, lucene

I have data, which looks like that:

```
  <doc>
    <str name="id">0000001</str>
    <str name="title">myItemTitle1</str>
    <arr name="myelements">
      <str>first element</str>
      <str>second element</str>
      <str>third element</str>
      ...
      <str>last element</str>
    </arr>
    <float name="weight">200.2</float>
    <long name="version">3499566</long>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">0000002</str>
    <str name="title">myItemTitle2</str>
    <arr name="myelements">
      <str>first element of second array</str>
      <str>second element of second array</str>
      <str>third element of second array</str>
      ...
      <str>last element of second array</str>
    </arr>
    <float name="weight">500.2</float>
    <long name="version">3499544</long>
  </doc>
  ...
```

My intention is to get .csv output of all elements in array "myelements" and so far I was able to get with next query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*%3A*&fl=myelements&wt=csv&start=1&rows=100
```

which gives me .csv lines:

```
  myelements
  "first element, second element, third element, last element"
  "first element of second array, second element of second array, third element of second array, last element of second array"
```

How can I modify above so I'll get **1 element from array per line** including **id**, i.e. like:

```
  myelements
  0000001, "first element"
  0000001, "second element"
  0000001, "third element"
  0000001, "last element"
  0000002, "first element of second array"
  0000002, "second element of second array"
  0000002, "third element of second array"
  0000002, "last element of second array"
```

Can it be done in Solr directly?

Answer (score 0):

just add another type of docs to the index that contain:

- id
- myelements: a single value from the array
- type:arraypair

then you can query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*%3A*&fq=type:arraypair&fl=myelements&wt=csv&start=1&rows=100
```

Or, you could implement your our response writer (inheriting from [CSVResponseWriter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/response/CSVResponseWriter.html)) that does what you want, but that would be more work I guess.